# how do Transcendental Meditation and mindfulness differ in terms of dealing with individual's anxiety?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, emotion, meditation, mindfulness

I want to know how these two forms of approaches differ in terms of guiding a person's anxiety and helping them heal. there has been no research done using these two forms of meditation together on testing anxiety. they have been studied separately. So I had wanted to know, how they differ in terms of helping anxious individuals.
after reading this article i wanted to suggest understanding from the behalf of others, as i am new here :)
refrence: 
Tacón, Anna M., et al. "Mindfulness meditation, anxiety reduction, and heart disease: a pilot study." Family & community health 26.1 (2003): 25-33.